# Align halves of splitted image - responsive

Tags: jquery, html, image, css

i have a “clickable puzzle-slideshow" running at the moment, that behaves as as background-size:cover. In narrow browser windows however, the aspect ratio & the cover effect get squished. Is there any way to preserve the aspect ratio, as well as the cover effect?
fiddle at: http://jsfiddle.net/L84wj5my/

The used method for trying to preserve is this one; but i am open to any solution:

```
.cover {
position: fixed; 
top: 0; 
left: 0; 

min-width: 100%;
min-height: 100%;
}
```

```js
$('#two li').click(changeImage);

function changeImage() {
  if($(this).is(':first-child')) {
    $(this).fadeOut(0).parent().find(':last-child').fadeIn(0);
  } else {
    $(this).fadeOut(0).prev().fadeIn(0);
  }
}


$('#one li').click(changeImage);

function changeImage() {
  if($(this).is(':first-child')) {
    $(this).fadeOut(0).parent().find(':last-child').fadeIn(0);
  } else {
    $(this).fadeOut(0).prev().fadeIn(0);
  }
}
```

```css
body, ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body,html{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;

}

ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.slides-box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slides {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  float: left;
}

.slides li {
  position: absolute;
  width:  100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.slides li img{
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
}






.slides-box-left {
  float:left;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: auto;
}

.slides-left {
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  float:none;
}

.slides-left li {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100% !important;
  float: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-position: left !important;
}

.slides-left img{
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  float:left;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.slides-left li img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 200%;
  height: auto !important;
}


.cover {
  position: fixed; 
  top: 0; 
  left: 0; 

  /* Preserve aspet ratio */
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slides-box">
  <ul id="one" class="slides" >
    <li>
      <img src="https://unsplash.it/2560/1600?image=764" class="cover">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="https://unsplash.it/2560/1600?image=763" class="cover">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="https://unsplash.it/2560/1600?image=762" class="cover">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="https://unsplash.it/2560/1600?image=761" class="cover">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="https://unsplash.it/2560/1600?image=760" class="cover">
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="left">
  <div class="slides-box-left">
    <ul id="two" class="slides-left">
      <li>
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/2560/1600?image=760" class="cover">
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/2560/1600?image=761" class="cover">
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/2560/1600?image=762" class="cover">
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/2560/1600?image=763" class="cover">
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/2560/1600?image=764" class="cover">
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

***[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/paduka/1/edit?html,css,js,output)*** (Click on left right and see the **background-image** halfs match perfectly)

**Don't use images** if you're concerned about making it simple and *ratio*nable.
Use `DIV` and `background-size` set to `cover`

Assign background-images paths in HTML (like you'd do it for img):

```
<!-- The underneath 100% slides -->
<div class="slides">
  <div style="background-image:url(https://unsplash.it/2560/1600?image=761)"></div>
  <div style="background-image:url(https://unsplash.it/2560/1600?image=762)"></div>
  <div style="background-image:url(https://unsplash.it/2560/1600?image=763)"></div>
</div>

<!-- The 50% overflow overlaying left slides -->
<div class="slides left">
  <div style="background-image:url(https://unsplash.it/2560/1600?image=763)"></div>
  <div style="background-image:url(https://unsplash.it/2560/1600?image=762)"></div>
  <div style="background-image:url(https://unsplash.it/2560/1600?image=761)"></div>
</div>
```

now the CSS magic using: `background: none 50% / cover;` and `width:200%` for the DIVs inside the overflowing 50% width left overlaying container:

```
*{margin:0;}
html, body{height:100%;}

.slides{
  position:fixed;
  overflow:hidden;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}

.slides div{
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background: none 50% / cover;
}

.slides.left{
  width:50%;
}

.slides.left div{
  width:200%; /* since .left is 50% */
}
```

I see you have issues fading your elements so here you go with a brand-new jQuery:

```
$(".slides").each(function(){

  var $bg = $(this).find("> div"),
      n = $bg.length, // how many images we have?
      c = 0; // counter

  $bg.hide().on("click", function(){ // Hide all and do on click:
    $bg.fadeOut().eq( ++c % n ).stop().fadeIn();   // Increment and loop
  }).eq(c).show(); // Show first initially.

});
```

See this demo and RUN it for a preview:

```js
$(".slides").each(function(){
  
  var $bg = $(this).find("> div"),
      n = $bg.length, // how many images we have?
      c = 0; // counter

  $bg.hide().on("click", function(){ // Hide all and do on click:
    $bg.fadeOut().eq( ++c % n ).stop().fadeIn();   // Increment and loop
  }).eq(c).show(); // Show first initially.
  
});
```

```css
*{margin:0;}
html, body{height:100%;}

.slides{
  position:fixed;
  overflow:hidden;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}

.slides div{
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background: none 50% / cover;
}

.slides.left{
  width:50%;
}

.slides.left div{
  width:200%; /* since .left is 50% */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- The underneath 100% slides -->
    <div class="slides">
      <div style="background-image:url(https://unsplash.it/2560/1600?image=761)"></div>
      <div style="background-image:url(https://unsplash.it/2560/1600?image=762)"></div>
      <div style="background-image:url(https://unsplash.it/2560/1600?image=763)"></div>
    </div>

    <!-- The 50% overflow overlaying left slides -->
    <div class="slides left">
      <div style="background-image:url(https://unsplash.it/2560/1600?image=763)"></div>
      <div style="background-image:url(https://unsplash.it/2560/1600?image=762)"></div>
      <div style="background-image:url(https://unsplash.it/2560/1600?image=761)"></div>
    </div>
```